# How to extract the maps via AC Dashboard?

Tags: azerothcore

I ran into the problem that everything went well with the compilation and the database. But when I start the worldserver, I get an error

```html
Loading world information...
> RealmID:              1
> Version DB world:     ACDB 335.6-dev
Will clear `logs` table of entries older than 1209600 seconds every 10 minutes.
Using DataDir /azerothcore-wotlk/data/
WORLD: VMap support included. LineOfSight:true, getHeight:true, indoorCheck:true PetLOS:true
Map file '/azerothcore-wotlk/data/maps/0004331.map': does not exist!
exit code: 1
worldserver terminated, restarting...
worldserver Terminated after 1 seconds, termination count: : 6
worldserver Restarter exited. Infinite crash loop prevented. Please check your system
```

What could be the problem? I rechecked the permissions to the directory including the owner and everything is fine. Tried different paths DataDir, now it set to **DataDir = "/home/azcore/azerothcore-wotlk/data". I get an error, how to fix that?
**

Comment: I fixed that with downloading via wget maps from this repo https://github.com/wowgaming/client-data/releases/tag/v13. 
But i don't know it's good or not.

Comment: it's good to use the already extracted data, no worries!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you only need to get latest maps compatible with AzerothCore you can download them from [here](https://github.com/wowgaming/client-data/releases).

Otherwise, change in your `config.sh` file `CTOOLS_BUILD='all'`, afterwards, run again the build using

```
./acore.sh compiler build
```

This will generate the binaries to extract the data inside `azerothcore-wotlk/env/dist/bin/`.
Having the binaries you can follow the guide [here](https://www.azerothcore.org/wiki/linux-server-setup) to extract them manually, you only need to move the binaries into the WoW directory and run the binaries in the right order.